# How to create an array of User Controls / indexing user controls in C# / Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, arrays, user-controls, controls

I am an old time user of the Array of controls in VB back in the days. It is gone now, so I am looking for a replacement.

I have created an User Control in C# for Silverlight. This control exposes a bool property IsChecked.

```
<ImageButton Name"imgbutton1" IsChecked="True"/>
<ImageButton Name"imgbutton2" IsChecked="False"/>
<ImageButton Name"imgbutton3" IsChecked="False"/>
```

In a Child Window, I populate a series of these controls and use them as an equivalent of RadioButtons, i.e., when I click one, any other that has an IsChecked = true will be set to false, for which I thought of doing something like:

```
List<ImageButton> imgButtons= new List<ImageButton>();
imgButtons.Add(imgbutton1);
imgButtons.Add(imgbutton2);
imgButtons.Add(imgbutton3);
```

Then, to clear all of their IsChecked but the one I need (pointed by some 'index' variable), I would do something like:

```
foreach (ImageButton imgbutton in imgButtons) imgbutton.IsChecked = false;
imgbuttons[index].IsChecked = true;
```

The problem I have is that `List<ImageButton>` is not compiling. I am very flaky at collections and can't figure out what I am missing. I can do for standard controls but doesn't allow me to get a user control in there.

Thanks!

PS: I have thought of just customizing a RadioButton control but don't have Blend and I am using this image control for other types of controls. However, if you think there is a better way to implement this, please let me know.

EDIT: Compiler says "The type or namespace name 'ImageButton' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have a reference to your "ImageButton" control in your code (in the "using" part).

To do that automatically you can just rightclick on your "ImageButton" in your code and click "Resolve", it will automatically add the Reference

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was missing. Since it resides all within the same namespace, I didn't know I had to add a reference to the control I created. I was assuming that since I added it to the Child Window, it was also visible in code behind. I can see the reference in XAML.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us what the compiler error was when you said *"List is not compiling"*.

My guess is that you need to include the namespace of the List collection in your file.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of something else, I'm not sure why you are keeping a List<> of your ImageButtons if they are in the display (in that childwindow).  If they are all within the same container your could use something like :

```
// here "grd" is your Grid container, it could be another type of container though
foreach (ImageButton imgBtn in grd.Children.OfType<ImageButton>())
                imgBtn.IsChecked = false;
```

Comment: I keep a list for indexing purposes. All these imagebuttons are acting like a RadioButton, passing the selected item to its caller. If I need to set one of these buttons, I just call its index rather than by control name. Makes sense?

Comment: Well you can get the actual index of a child object using grd.Children.IndexOf(imgBtn);.  To retrieve the same item with the index : grd.Children[i].

Comment: This is an interesting solution too. Only that I would have to create a mapping between the caller's index and the grd.Children.IndexOf(imgButton).

Answer (score -1):

This may help.

The code for user control:

```
//usercontrol1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        Color formcolor;
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        public void setvals(string a1,string a2,string a3,string a4)
        {
            t1.Text=a1;
            t2.Text=a2;
            t3.Text=a3;
            t4.Text=a4;
        }

        public Color formColor
        {
            get
            {
                return formcolor;
            }
            set
            {
                formcolor = value;
                this.BackColor = formcolor;
            }
        }

    }
}





usercontrol.designer.cs

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class UserControl1
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.t1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.t2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.t3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.t4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // t1
            // 
            this.t1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 16);
            this.t1.Name = "t1";
            this.t1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.t1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // t2
            // 
            this.t2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 42);
            this.t2.Name = "t2";
            this.t2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.t2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // t3
            // 
            this.t3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 68);
            this.t3.Name = "t3";
            this.t3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.t3.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // t4
            // 
            this.t4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 94);
            this.t4.Name = "t4";
            this.t4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.t4.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // UserControl1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.t4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.t3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.t2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.t1);
            this.Name = "UserControl1";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(278, 133);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox t1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox t2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox t3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox t4;
    }
}
```

now in the form totally dynamically can create an array of that user control like this

A global variable

```
   private UserControl1[] userControl11=new WindowsFormsApplication1.UserControl1[3];
```

and now the array of user control

you can write it on a button

```
this.SuspendLayout();
            Random r=new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {

                userControl11[i] = new UserControl1();
                this.userControl11[i].formColor = Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255),r.Next(255),r.Next(255));
                this.userControl11[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(133 , 133*(i+1));
                this.userControl11[i].Name = "userControl11";
                this.userControl11[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(278, 133);
                this.userControl11[i].TabIndex = 0;
                this.Controls.Add(this.userControl11[i]);
            }
            ;
```